# Viable use of genetic algorithms to train neural nets in a poker bot?

Tags: performance, neural-network, simulation, genetic-algorithm, poker

I am designing a bot to play Texas Hold'Em Poker on tables of up to ten players, and the design includes a few feed forward neural networks (FFNN). These neural nets each have 8 to 12 inputs, 2 to 6 outputs, and 1 or 2 hidden layers, so there are a few hundred weights that I have to optimize. My main issue with training through back propagation is getting enough training data. I play poker in my spare time, but not enough to gather data on my own. I have looked into purchasing a few million hands off of a poker site, but I don't think my wallet will be very happy with me if I do... So, I have decided on approaching this by designing a genetic algorithm. I have seen examples of FFNNs being trained to play games like Super Mario and Tetris using genetic algorithms, but never for a game like poker, so I want to know if this is a viable approach to training my bot.

First, let me give a little background information (this may be confusing if you are unfamiliar with poker). I have a system in place that allows the bot to put its opponents on a specific range of hands so that it can make intelligent decisions accordingly, but it relies entirely on accurate output from three different neural networks:
NN_1) This determines how likely it is that an opponent is a) playing the actual value of his hand, b) bluffing, or c) playing a hand with the potential to become stronger later on.
NN_2) This assumes the opponent is playing the actual value of his hand and outputs the likely strength. It represents option (a) from the first neural net.
NN_3) This does the same thing as NN_2 but instead assumes the opponent is bluffing, representing option (b).
Then I have an algorithm for option (c) that does not use a FFNN. The outputs for (a), (b), and (c) are then combined based on the output from NN_1 to update my opponent's range.

Whenever the bot is faced with a decision (i.e. should it fold, call, or raise?), it calculates which is most profitable based on its opponents' hand ranges and how they are likely to respond to different bet sizes. This is where the fourth and final neural net comes in. It takes inputs based on properties unique to each player and the state of the table, and it outputs the likelihood of the opponent folding, calling, or raising.

The bot will also have a value for aggression (how likely it is to raise instead of call) and its opening range (which hands to play pre-flop). These four neural networks and two values will define each generation of bots in my genetic algorithm.

Here is my plan for training:
I will be simulating multiple large tournaments with 10<sup>n</sup> initial bots each with random values for everything. For the first few dozen tournaments, they will all be placed on tables of 10. They will play until either one bot is left or they play, say, 1,000 hands. If they reach that hand limit, the remaining bots will instantly go all-in every hand until one is left. After each table has completed, the most accurate FFNNs will be placed in the winning bot that will move on to the next round (even if the bot containing the best FFNN was not the winner). The winning bot will retain its aggression and opening range values. The tournament ends when only 100 bots remain, and random variations on those bots will generate the players for the next tournament. I'm assuming the first few tournaments will be complete chaos, so I don't want to narrow down my options too much early on.

If by some miracle, the bots actually develop a profitable, or at least somewhat coherent, strategy (I will check for this periodically), I will begin decreasing the amount of variation between bots. Anyone who plays poker could tell you that there are different types of players each with different strategies. I want to make sure that I am allowing enough room for different strategies to develop throughout this process. Then I may develop some sort of "super bot" that can switch between those different strategies if one is failing.

So, are there any glaring issue with this approach? If so, how would you recommend fixing them? Do you have any advice for speeding up this process or increasing my chances of success? I just want to make sure I'm not about to waste hundreds of hours on something doomed to fail. Also, if this site is not the correct place to be asking this question, please refer me to another website before flagging this. I would really appreciate it. Thanks all!

Comment: This question might be a better match on cs.stackexchange.com? I'm not sure.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it there too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to use ANN for poker bot. It is better to think for expert system. You can use odds calculator to have numerical evaluation of the hand strength and after that expert system for money management (risk management). ANNs are good in other problems.

Comment: My thought was that I would use the NN to predict human behavior since that is not easily determined with a formula and varies based on quite a few different parameters. I use pure odds and estimated gains/losses for everything else. I need to find a reliable way to predict an opponent's hand strength and how they would respond to bet sizing, so I was hoping a NN would be able to find patterns that I could not.

Comment: First of all you can not be sure who is playing against you (people are different in different games with different behaviour). Second of all even single person changes his/her behaviour according to the situation (this is one of the things in which humans are better than computers). If you like to analyze opponent's behaviour it is much better to try rule engine with knowledge base (expert system). Anti fraud systems in the gambling industry are working in this way. I have learned about such system when I was working for Playtech Bulgaria.